# How to move the last n files in hdfs

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have a folder in HDFS contains 1000000 files, and I want to move the last "8797" files after sorting based on datetime to another folder in HDFS? I tried using xargs but didn't work fine. Any other ideas?

Here is the exact split point between all files. I want to move files after "2021-03-09 15:15"

`-rw-rw-r--+  3 talend_user talend_group     102013 2021-03-09 15:14 /user/file_1`

`-rw-rw-r--+  3 talend_user talend_group       9360 2021-03-09 15:15 /user/file_2`

Comment: What does mean last? is it created time?

Comment: Thanks for noting that. Yes, the last n files after sorting based on datetime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ls -t to sort files by modification time:

```
./hadoop-2.10.0/bin/hadoop fs -ls -t /tmp/
```

and then extract file names from eighth column:

```
 ./hadoop-2.10.0/bin/hadoop fs -ls -t /tmp/ | awk '{print $8}'
```

Save this output to a file:

```
./hadoop-2.10.0/bin/hadoop fs -ls -t /tmp/ | awk '{print $8}' > test.txt
```

At last use tail -n to extract last n files.

```
tail -n 8797 test.txt
```

Or in one command as below:

```
 ./hadoop-2.10.0/bin/hadoop fs -ls -t /tmp/ | awk '{print $8}' | tail -n8797
```

Now you can move your files by this output with help of pipe command in linux.
Based your problem, you may need `head` instead of `tail`.

**UPDATE**:

Move your files by something like this:

```
./hadoop-2.10.0/bin/hadoop fs -cp  `./hadoop-2.10.0/bin/hadoop fs -ls -t /tmp/ | awk '{print $8}' | tail -n3` /newdirectory
```

Comment: Great, I got the file names that are required, but how to proceed with "pipe command in linux" that you mentioned?